# If a sequence $(f_n)$ do not converge uniformly, then no subsequence of $(f_n)$ converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Can someone verify this claim:

> If a sequence $(f_n)$ do not converge uniformly, then no subsequence
>   of $(f_n)$ converge uniformly

I saw this in a proof, where $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $x \in [0,1]$, the claim it is well known that the above sequence is not uniformly convergent, therefore no subsequence of $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent

Comment: I sure hope this wasn't a proof in a published paper.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thankfully it wasn't. It was just a list of "must to knows" from a professor to prepare his class for the final exam on real analysis :)

Comment: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/pubvit/Downloads/ArzNotes/ArzNotes.pdf

If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is continuous. Here the limit function is not continuous, but every function in the sequence is. Any subsequence will have the same limit function which is not continuous at 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim isn't true in general. Suppose that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly, and define $g_{2n}=f_n$, $g_{2n+1}=0$. Then $g_n$ does not converge to zero uniformly, but a subsequence does.

Comment: So we cannot deduce $f_n(x)  = x^n$ has no uniformly convergent subsequence from the claim...

Comment: @TheSilence it's easy to deduce that sequence has no uniformly convergent subsequence from the fact that the limit is not continuous. If some subsequence converged uniformly the limit would be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_{2n-1}\equiv 1$ and $f_{2n}=x^{2n}.$ Then $(f_n)$ doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ but the subsequence $(f_{2n-1})$ do.

**Edit to answer the comment**

$f_n=x^n$ has no any subsequence converging uniformly on $[0,1].$ Argue by contradiction. If such a subsequence converges uniformly the limit function must be continuous on $[0,1].$ But the pointwise limit is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & if \: 0\le x<1 \\ 1 & if \: x=1.\end{cases}$$ This is not a continuous function on $[0,1],$ but it should be if there were a uniformly convergent subsequence. So, we are done.

Comment: So is it still possible to deduce that $f_n(x) = x^n$ has no uniformly convergent subsequence?

Comment: Exactly.  That was the point.

Answer (score 0):

Even if  each $f_n$ is continuous and $(f_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence converging pointwise but not uniformly to a continuous $f,$ it may have a uniformly convergent sub-sequence.  For example, let $f_{2 n}(x)=0$ for all $x.$ Let $f_{2 n-1}(x)=0$ for $x\not \in [0,2/n],\;$ $f_{2 n-1}(x)=n x$ for $x\in [0,1/n],\;$ and $f_{2 n-1}(x)=2-n x$ for $x\in [1/n,2/n].$ And $f=0.$ Then $(f_{2 n})_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f.$